# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to create a setup command in my bot where the user can choose what he wants. The problem is I can' get it to work as I want to.

I have this as my code

```
# Function to write changes to file
def set_adminrole(guild: Guild, *, role: Role):
    with open("admins.json") as f:
        roles = json.load(f)

    roles[str(guild.id)] = role.id

    with open("admins.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(roles, f, indent=4)

# Actual command

-- Not important code --

await ctx.send(f"Now, mention the role you want it to be the admin role")
    role: Message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    actualrole: Role = Role(role)
    set_adminrole(ctx.message.guild, role=actualrole)
    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to {Role(role.content).mention}... Let's keep going")
```

When I mention a role to set it as teh admin role it throws this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command setup:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Ficheiros/Pastas/Tudo/Coding/Python/Projects/Server-Utils/bot.py", line 262, in start_setup
    actualrole: Role = Role(role)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Your question does not have enough info. Take a look at the logs, you'll find something telling you what is causing the error, perhaps this:  ```...Server-Utils/bot.py", line 262, in start_setup```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Since you failed to provide appropriate support for the `Role` class, and your posted code fails to run on many counts, we can't do much for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you receive a message, and then attempt to create a Role object using the message. Which makes no sense. Look at the constructor for Role objects, and call it correctly.

```
await ctx.send(f"Now, mention the role you want it to be the admin role")
    role: Message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    actualrole: Role = Role(role) #<- what are you doing here????
    set_adminrole(ctx.message.guild, role=actualrole)
    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to
```

Comment: I have no idea how to get the mentioned role from the message... Can you tell me how to do so?

Comment: There are a variety of ways. You could look at the message content and parse it out. You could change your command so that it’s a parameter to the command and use the role converter. Try looking at what all is contained in the message you get back first. Use a debugger, or use the “dir” command

Comment: Yep, figured it out. Tnx <3

Comment: Great!  Feel free to upvote or accept. Best of luck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I retrieved the content of the message that would be `<@&123456789>` being `123456789` the id of the role I mentioned. removed the `<, @, & and >` from the string and got left with only the id. Just used `discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=123456789)` and boom. Thank you all for the help

Comment: You should look into the role converter.... it is meant to be used in the command definition, but I use them internally in functions. It’s still useful.